# Compiling Hello World example from OpenVDB

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

i have encountered some problems as below:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) const openvdb::v3_0_0::tree::TreeBase::`vftable'" (__imp_??_7TreeBase@tree@v3_0_0@openvdb@@6B@)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __cdecl openvdb::v3_0_0::GridBase::saveFloatAsHalf(void)const " (__imp_?saveFloatAsHalf@GridBase@v3_0_0@openvdb@@QEBA_NXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl openvdb::v3_0_0::util::printBytes(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,unsigned __int64,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,bool,int,int)" (__imp_?printBytes@util@v3_0_0@openvdb@@YAHAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@_KAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@5@2_NHH@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static bool __cdecl openvdb::v3_0_0::Metadata::isRegisteredType(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_?isRegisteredType@Metadata@v3_0_0@openvdb@@SA_NAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class boost::shared_ptr<class openvdb::v3_0_0::Metadata> __cdecl openvdb::v3_0_0::Metadata::createMetadata(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_?createMetadata@Metadata@v3_0_0@openvdb@@SA?AV?$shared_ptr@VMetadata@v3_0_0@openvdb@@@boost@@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl openvdb::v3_0_0::math::Transform::print(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)const " (__imp_?print@Transform@math@v3_0_0@openvdb@@QEBAXAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@6@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl openvdb::v3_0_0::initialize(void)" (__imp_?initialize@v3_0_0@openvdb@@YAXXZ)
```

Codes:

```
#include <openvdb/openvdb.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib,"openvdb.lib")
int main()
{
    // Initialize the OpenVDB library.  This must be called at least
    // once per program and may safely be called multiple times.
    openvdb::initialize();
    // Create an empty floating-point grid with background value 0. 
    openvdb::FloatGrid::Ptr grid = openvdb::FloatGrid::create();
    std::cout << "Testing random access:" << std::endl;
    // Get an accessor for coordinate-based access to voxels.
    openvdb::FloatGrid::Accessor accessor = grid->getAccessor();
    // Define a coordinate with large signed indices.
    openvdb::Coord xyz(1000, -200000000, 30000000);

    // Set the voxel value at (1000, -200000000, 30000000) to 1.
    accessor.setValue(xyz, 1.0);

    // Verify that the voxel value at (1000, -200000000, 30000000) is 1.
    std::cout << "Grid" << xyz << " = " << accessor.getValue(xyz) << std::endl;

    // Reset the coordinates to those of a different voxel.
    xyz.reset(1000, 200000000, -30000000);

    // Verify that the voxel value at (1000, 200000000, -30000000) is
    // the background value, 0.
    std::cout << "Grid" << xyz << " = " << accessor.getValue(xyz) << std::endl;

    // Set the voxel value at (1000, 200000000, -30000000) to 2.
    accessor.setValue(xyz, 2.0);
    // Set the voxels at the two extremes of the available coordinate space.
    // For 32-bit signed coordinates these are (-2147483648, -2147483648, -2147483648)
    // and (2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647).
    accessor.setValue(openvdb::Coord::min(), 3.0f);
    accessor.setValue(openvdb::Coord::max(), 4.0f);
    std::cout << "Testing sequential access:" << std::endl;
    // Print all active ("on") voxels by means of an iterator.
    for (openvdb::FloatGrid::ValueOnCIter iter = grid->cbeginValueOn(); iter; ++iter) {
        std::cout << "Grid" << iter.getCoord() << " = " << *iter << std::endl;
    }
}
```

FYI, i have built the openvdb.lib file using guidelines from Rama in OpenVDB forum. However, when i try to build the hello world example as below, it complains about linker errors. I have included the include directories as well as library directories and even specify #pragma comment to include the openvdb.lib.

FYI, the built OpenVDB library is a static library built out from VS2010.

Thus, can i know what possibly gone wrong or maybe the way i am using it is wrong??

Comment: Linker errors mean that you forgot to link the library so the linker doesn't find the code to run the library functions. You can go to your project options then linker/input and add the library files in the lib folder

Comment: @meneldal, hi, i have already added those libs and header folder in the include as well as additional library directories.

Comment: If you did add the required libs to the linker, it might be because the compilation of the lib didn't go correctly and it skipped over some functions.

Comment: @meneldal, the other libs are well compiled coz they are the prerequisites before openvdb is to be compiled. So i am quite sure that the prerequisite libraries didnt have any problem to do with it. However, the errors just seem to play with openvdb.lib. Thanks

Comment: The symbols the system is not finding are obviously from openvdb.lib Are you sure you put in in your include path and it's linking fine?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is linking fine, but i havent got any syntax errors from that. Is there any way to test the linkage??

Comment: there should be a warning a bit before that says "couldn't find openvdb.lib" for example

Comment: I think i havent encountered this warning or error before, so, i think it linked fine. BTW, is the code generation option will affect the output(code generation->runtime library)

Comment: well it might as in it will either work fine or break but usually that's pretty binary

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://nidclip.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/compiling-openvdb-the-openvdb-viewer-on-windows-7/) website, you need to include the following files in your project (add them in project options/linker/input)

```
glew32d.lib
glu32.lib
opengl32.lib
GLFW.lib
zlibstat.lib
Half.lib
```

Then it seems you also need to change another option:

```
Add /FORCE:MULTIPLE to the command line linker options under Linker > Command Line
```

This should be the right settings to compile your test project.

Comment: Hi, I have added the required lib to the current project. However, can i know what do you mean by `Add /FORCE:MULTIPLE to the command line linker options under Linker > Command Line`

Comment: Well in the linker options there is also the "command line" option. You can add options that will go to the linker. It might work without it, that's the first time I've heard of this option actually even after using Visual Studio with many libraries.

Comment: I have tried to add the `\FORCE:MULTIPLE` to the command line but the result remains the same

Comment: Hi, can i know what is the problem in regards of __declspec(dllimport)??

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy.aspx basically that's the linkage you give to items in a dll (things you can access from the outside). You might have used the wrong options when building your library since you wanted to make a static one

Comment: Ya, coz i am just following the guide from the guidelines and get the lib as the result. BTW, after i added the \FORCE option in the command line, i get this warning `image being generated due to /FORCE option; image may not run` and after changing the code generation method

Comment: I have changed the code generation method from MT dll to just MT and i did have the build succeeded, yet, there is supposed to be some kind of output to the command line but i didnt have those.

Comment: The command line output might depend on other setting in your project. What kind oif project did you create?

Comment: I have tried f5 to run the project but what i get is "exe has stopped working"

Comment: well at least run it in debug to see where it fails

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the runtime library options(/MT or /MD) are consistent in your libs.

Comment: Hi, FYI, i have verified that i have built all those libraries with /MD

Answer (score -1):

glew32d.lib, glu32.lib, opengl32.lib, and GLFW.lib  are NOT required for the code at the top.  They are only required if someone is compiling the separate viewer app.  The code example creates a grid container, writes values into it, and reads the values back.

This is a problem people are having with the code and seems to work on some systems but not others.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Ideally, answers not only point out the problem in the code but offer either a solution or a suggested way to work around the problem. If you cannot help the user or are unsure, usually people just leave a comment on the original question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but i have managed to sort it out, yes, the hello dont really need the glew library as it didnt utilize any viewer to view the openvdb grid. However, the way to make this compile is actually to change the preprocessor as in this link http://www.openvdb.org/forum/?place=msg%2Fopenvdb-forum%2F-jFJQ2N4BGc%2Fo9LweytABfAJ. Thanks